# Unable to upload files with Flutter Dio multipartFile

Tags: flutter, dart, dio, imagepicker, multipartfile

I set up [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) as a http client to upload image files to my server. I'm using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker). Initially, when I set it up like a month ago, it worked fine. But I later found out it stopped working. It still works on Android emulator but not on a physical device.

Comment: Removing the info on your own trace analysis probably was not helpful for your questions chances for answers. Please reconsider that edit. Compare [ask].

Answer (score 1):

After getting the solution to this, I felt I should delete this answer as the solution seems kinda obvious. But on a second thought, I'll leave it in because this answer might save someone hours of debug.
I found out that the images files were large and the uploading process didn't complete before Dio.sendTimeout returns. So I increase the sendTimeout and reduced the size of the image file (picked using Image_picker) PickedFile.imageQuality.